# How to unit test CompletableFuture.thenAccept() by avoiding manual sleep

Tags: java-8, completable-future

How to avoid manual sleep in unit test. 
Suppose In below code the `Process` and `notify` takes around 5 seconds for processing. So in order to complete the processing, i have added sleep of 5 seconds.

```
public class ClassToTest {

    public ProcessService processService;
    public NotificationService notificationService;

    public ClassToTest(ProcessService pService ,NotificationService nService ) {
        this.notificationService=nService;
        this.processService = pService;
    }
    public CompletableFuture<Void> testMethod()
    {
          return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(processService::process)
                        .thenAccept(notificationService::notify);
    }

}
```

is there any better way to handle this ?

```
 @Test
    public void comletableFutureThenAccept() {
         CompletableFuture<Void> thenAccept = 
          sleep(6);
          assertTrue(thenAccept.isDone());  
          verify(mocknotificationService, times(1)).notify(Mockito.anystring());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does this method test? The assumption that the other method will always complete within five seconds? And the methods under test are within the same class as the unit test?

Comment: method under test are not in  same Test class, This is just to show some sample code.The method which want to test is in other class and injected in my Test class. I want to understand how can i avoid sleep in unit Test. As my system under test (Some method can take random amount of time)

Comment: The test as shown, does not test anything, except that the method will eventually complete (or within that arbitrary time interval of five seconds). What is this method *actually* supposed to test?

Comment: updated the code..sorry for creating confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, you want to test whether an underlying operation completes with the intended result, has the intended side effect, or at least completes without throwing an exception. This can be achieved as easy as

```
@Test
public void comletableFutureThenAccept() {
      CompletableFuture<Void> future = someMethod();
      future.join();
      /* check for class under test to have the desired state */
}
```

`join()` will wait for the completion and return the result (which you can ignore in case of `Void`), throwing an exception if the future completed exceptionally.

If completing withing a certain time is actually part of the test, simply use

```
@Test(timeout = 5000)
public void comletableFutureThenAccept() {
      CompletableFuture<Void> future = someMethod();
      future.join();
      /* check for class under test to have the desired state */
}
```

In the unlikely case that you truly want to test for completion within the specified time only, i.e. do not care whether the operation threw an exception, you can use

```
@Test(timeout = 5000)
public void comletableFutureThenAccept() {
      CompletableFuture<Void> future = someMethod();
      future.exceptionally(t -> null).join();
}
```

This substitutes an exceptional completion with a `null` result, hence, `join()` won’t throw an exception. So only the timeout remains.

Java 9 allows another alternative, not using JUnit’s timeout.

```
@Test()
public void comletableFutureThenAccept() {
      CompletableFuture<Void> future = someMethod().orTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      future.join();
      /* check for class under test to have the desired state */
}
```

This has the advantage of not failing if the operation completes in time but the subsequent verification takes longer.

Comment: Thanks, Yes this is what i was looking. Join and  orTimeout will solve my problem